# how to convert to log mel spectrogram in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I tried to modify my preprocess function to create log-mel-spectrogram so that my CNN model can train on it.

I tried to use convert my spectrogram to log-mel-spectrogram, but I was not able to do it. However, since I am using tensorflow, this converting process needs to be using tensorflow framework.

```
def preprocess(file_path, label): 
    wav = load_wav_16k_mono(file_path)
    wav = wav[:8000]
    zero_padding = tf.zeros([8000] - tf.shape(wav), dtype=tf.float32)
    wav = tf.concat([zero_padding, wav],0)
    
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(wav, frame_length=100, frame_step=20)
    spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
    spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, axis=2)
    
    return spectrogram, label
```